# What to look for in Riding Suits?

Tags: product-rec, clothes

I have been using a riding jacket but it is a bit hot during summer over long trips. I like the jacket because it is very simple, only one pocket for a key and it protects in accidents (or so I think).

I have now used a so-called "technical t-shirt" used by footballers and armies as underwear. It moves the moisture out of the skin so my body temperature is more stable even with the jacket. I have replaced my cotton t-shirt under the jacket with it and I feel much better with it. I am unsure why but it works, ideas about such layered bicycling welcome.

I have been considering to buy this suit [here](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/2010-armstrong-radio-shack-team-long-sleeves-bike-riding-suit-sports-clothes-size-l-175-180cm-52372) but I have no experience with them earlier. What should I look for with this kind of suits? And how do layers work here? Which layer moves the moisture, not to get cold etc?

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to tell if you'll like bike clothes without trying them on. Just from the picture, I'd think a kit like would be a bit hot for weather above 60-70 degrees F. How hot does it get by you in the summer? Do you need to cover up? Do you need something waterproof?

Comment: @Neil Fein: I can use my current clothes such as bicycle jacket if it gets too rainy or too cold. Yes, I think a cover-up is a good idea. I am now looking for something like ice-hockey players use as underneath clothes, something as convenient.

Comment: The base layers ice-hockey players use are going to overheat you. Hmm. Is this for modesty reasons or for shielding against the sun? (That would affect any recommendation.)

Comment: I've seen several people who for one reason or another avoid the sun on their skin using Tyvek suits while riding.  They apparently breathe fairly well and still offer good protection from the sun.  They're also fairly good as wind and rain wear.  Durability is not the greatest, but they're reasonably cheap.

Comment: Your URL for the suit seems to be a 404 now

Comment: What to look for in a riding suit? If you want a high probability of success, look for a wanker.

Answer (score 3):

For the wicking action to work you need to wear something that is relatively taut on the skin. [Any common jersey should do the job](http://www.bikejerseys.com/). I and others have had success with light weight [wool jerseys like from ibex](http://shop.ibex.com/Mens-Ride).

Generally speaking, cotton is not a good choice for the base layer next to your skin. It will work for a while but as soon as it gets drenched with sweat you'll be miserable.

Layering is key for colder weather. First knee and arm warmers, then a cap under helmet, and shoe covers, then a lightweight jacket or winter training jersey. After that, a "dicky" for your neck and tights over the bibs

Answer (score 1):

The suit you have linked to has a few red flags, if you are looking for cooler riding apparel. First, it is long sleeved and long pants. This is generally only the case if it is designed for cool weather riding, and so will be warm.

It is also rather loose fitting for cycling apparel, and it is also (apparently from the photos) thermal cloth. Also quite warm.

Last the suit is made mostly of polyester, which doesn't tend to breathe well. Look at something like [this](http://assos.com/en/19/singleProduct.aspx?cat=6,19,25&prod=319&var=441) for hot summer rides. Especially if you can pull off those stylin' shades. ;)

Edit: I was mostly basing my comments on @hhh's desire to avoid heat as stated in his OP. It also appears he is worried about safety which means covering up for protection. You really only get cool or covered, though, in my experience. Finding a balance is tough, and personal.

Comment: I would agree, but (not sure here), I *think* that it's important to @hhh to cover up.

Comment: It could be. I was mostly basing my comments on @hhh's desire to avoid heat as stated in his OP. It also appears he is worried about safety, so that is a possibility. You really only get cool or covered, though, in my experience. Finding a balance is tough, and personal.

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to have accidents, then armour (e.g. as worn by inline skaters) might be cool and protective: because it would only cover your points, e.g. elbows.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to 'layer' up or down is important if you want to be comfortable. Especially if your temperature won't  be consistent - if you cycle some where hilly your temperature will fluctuate quite a bit. If you have unsettled weather too this will cause the same effect.

I ride in a technical t-shirt with a waterproof jacket on top. The jacket has a mesh section on the back covered by a 'flap', which can be buttoned down (if raining), or left to flap about a bit and keep you ventilated.
The cuffs have velcro straps which when tightened stop air flowing into the arms.
The front zip is pretty self explanatory.
The jacket can be folded up and the fits into its own back pocket (inside out), and then velcro attached onto the top bar.

Altogether this kind of jacket allows you to cycle in multiple climates, and most importantly you can 'change climates' very quickly, without change outfit.

Sunny and warm: jacket on bike
wet and warm: jacket on, cuffs open, back closed
wet and cold: jacket on, cuffs and back closed

Long story short, get one jacket which is very flexible for purpose. Allowing you to adjust your outfit to maintain a level of comfort through varying conditions.
I use this set up on 200 kms without fail, and spending max 2 mins of the bike to adjust (folding up jacket to velcro onto bar if it's suddenly gotten hot and sunny).